# Guidance on a data mining project

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I am working on a data mining project for my class and I would like an expert point of view on my idea:

The data I have is a very large matrix with a lot more variables than examples (10,000,000 against 50), so there is an overfitting issue.

What I'm trying to do is make sense of this dataset by regrouping the variables into "groups" because I feel there should be a relationship between some of these variables (correlation). To do so, I defined a "distance" between the variables (Their Pearson Correlation).

I want to apply a clustering method to the variables to create these groups of variables (as advised by my professor).

My problem is that this dataset is so large, I know any clustering algorithm is gonna take a while to execute. Is there an clustering method that might fit better to this problem?

Comment: You ought to reduce the number of features. Almost nothing is going to work in a ten million space.

Comment: Consider using an software with **index support**, as this may help accelerating the algorithm. I found that some implementations (in particular in pure R, and Weka) are much slower than they need to be.

Comment: Oh, and if by chance the 10 million variables are *binary* or *discrete* (for example because they are from text), you may want to consider appropriate techniques for these specific domains. Such as stemming and stop word filtering for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try applying [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to reduce the number of features (which you refer to as variables if I understand correctly), and then apply any black box clustering algorithm.

You can use [PCA from sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) to achieve this.

A sample snippet goes like :

```
def decomposition_pca(train_data):
    dims_to_keep = #dimensions you want to retain (the # variables)
    """ Linear dimensionality reduction """
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components = dims_to_keep, whiten=True)
    train_pca = pca.fit_transform(train_data)
    return train_pca
```

Comment: do you have advice as for the clustering method after the application of PCA?

Comment: Since you have mentioned nothing about your data, I don't think I can pick one over the other. Starting with K-means will probably be a good idea.

Comment: PCA from sklean doesn't work for large datasets. I will probably use randomized pca

Comment: @teaLeef My aim was to point you to a possible solution. It is possible that you might have to use some other pca implementations.